# Installing NetBeans with Java support for Windows?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans

I have tried to install [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) and other Java SDK, plugin, etc.
But when I open NetBeans->New Project I can only open the [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) and PHP project.

Is there any way to add support to standard Java (console application)?

Comment: Have you explored Tools > Plugins on the menu bar? Try downloading from there the plugin named Java under Java SE category from the available plugins tab.

Comment: @Jonathan Day it would be http://programmers.stackexchange.com but, even so... *Programmers.SE is for subjective or extended discussions about programming-related issues that have no definitive answer, whereas Stack Overflow is for objective, technical, and pointed questions about programming that have a definitive answer.* And this question does seam to have a pretty objective answer.

Comment: @Frankie. Fair enough, deleted

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you have the correct NetBeans installer, have installed it correctly and also have at least one JDK already installed on your system. It very much sounds like either the wrong NetBeans was installed (I don't use it myself, I'm presuming there are a variety of different versions) or that NetBeans is not seeing a JDK on the system and therefore reconfigures itself so there is no java development.

Comment: Yes, you need the Java SE, or even better, ALL. You can choose them right here: http://netbeans.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

The Java website has a version that includes the JDK.

You can also install the JDK first and then install a version of Netbeans that includes Java support.

If the installer does not ask you which JDK you want to use, then you are not installing with Java support.